# replace data frame values in R with double conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have this data frame :

```
 A  B     C      D
 1  cola  light  0
 2  cola  light  0
 3  cola  lemon  0
 4  Pepsi lemon  0
 5  Pepsi lemon  0
```

I would like to do a double conditions into "B" and "C" and put the result in D, for example (pseudo code) :

```
 if B=="cola" and C=="light"
  D=10 else D=20
```

In R I used ifelse to do it ,but my problem is that B="Cola" or c="light" are always FALSE, i am java user and comparing strings or characters is more easier, I use (equals or compareTo). But in R i don't know how to handle this kind of problem, I tried as.character to transform it but no result. My conditions still retuning False.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please post the R code you're running that is always returning `FALSE`.

Comment: you want `==` which is a test for equality, `=` is an assignment

Comment: @josilber the R code that i run is the ifelse condition as proposed by zx8754 (df$D <- ifelse(df$B == "cola" & df$C == "light", 10, 20)), JeremyS i know this issue, the code below is just a pseudo code, i will edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or

```
 dat$D <- c(20,10)[(dat$B=="cola" & dat$C=="light")+1]
dat$D
#[1] 10 10 20 20 20
```

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(A = 1:5, B = c("cola", "cola", "cola", "Pepsi", 
"Pepsi"), C = c("light", "light", "lemon", "lemon", "lemon"), 
D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

#### Update

If your dataset columns are:

```
 dat$B <- c( " cola ", " cola", "cola ", "Pepsi", "Pepsi")
 c(20,10)[(dat$B=="cola" & dat$C=="light")+1]
 #[1] 20 20 20 20 20
```

In that case,

```
  c(20,10)[(grepl("cola", dat$B)&grepl("light", dat$C)) +1]
 #[1] 10 10 20 20 20
```

Or you could use `str_trim`

```
library(stringr)

dat[,2:3] <- lapply(dat[,2:3], str_trim) 
c(20,10)[(dat$B=="cola" & dat$C=="light")+1]
 #[1] 10 10 20 20 20
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df$D <- ifelse(df$B == "cola" & df$C == "light", 10, 20)
```

Comment: thank you, but it replace everything with 20 , it means that the condition return False. It's the same problem

Comment: This is what `ifelse` does, if condition is True do this otherwise (False) do that... please clarify your problem more.

Comment: yes i understand ifelse, but values of "C" are all 20 even if the condition is true (i have cola in B and light in C and it returns 20

Comment: @foboss, please provide `str` or `dput` of your data

Answer (score 1):

```
A <- 1:5
B <- c(rep("cola",3), rep("Pepsi", 2))
C <- c(rep("light",2), rep("lemon", 3))
D <- rep(0,5)
```

Then i have the data.frame exactly like yours

```
> data
  A     B     C D
1 1  cola light 0
2 2  cola light 0
3 3  cola lemon 0
4 4 Pepsi lemon 0
5 5 Pepsi lemon 0
```

according to @zx8754

```
> data$D <- ifelse(data$B=="cola" & data$C=="light", 10,20)
> data
  A     B     C  D
1 1  cola light 10
2 2  cola light 10
3 3  cola lemon 20
4 4 Pepsi lemon 20
5 5 Pepsi lemon 20
```

Comment: @userR i can not create the data frame as u did, because i am getting it from a data base and it's about 2240 observations, why it's not working? i still have false in both of conditions

Comment: then your problem would be data import from external database. may i know what kind of database you are using? MySQL? T

Comment: yes i am using Mysql, i just notice that "B" and "C" are Factor ,this can be a problem for ifelse?

Comment: still the same problem it replaces everything with 20, the condition is not fulfilled

Comment: It is OK to compare factor field with character string, no need to convert.

Comment: then maybe its problem to import data from mysql?